# linux socket programming: Socket writing line to a file in c

Tags: c, linux, file, sockets

Hi Guys I am having trouble trying to write to file. I am in networking class and we are supposed to implement a simple ftp server. It involves reading a file and sending it over the socket to a client. When it reaches the client then you write the output to a file. I have implemented a server and client and they both work fine when printed. However when I append to the file it works differently. The output comes out different. Instead of writing all the lines as before now only the first line is is being written to file or sometimes two lines.I don't know what is causing the problem. Here is the code. I pass buffer of size 4096.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


#define MAX_LENGTH 4096

int write_line(char string[MAX_LENGTH]){
    FILE *fp;

    char* array = strdup(string);
    char* filename="client.txt";
    char* dir=get_current_dir_name();

    char fullpath[MAX_LENGTH];

    strcat(fullpath, dir);
    strcat(fullpath, "/");
    strcat(fullpath, filename);

    fp=fopen(fullpath, "a");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        return -1 ; 
    }

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"%c",*(array+i));
    }
    fclose(fp);

    bzero(fullpath, MAX_LENGTH);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code prints the numeric value of each character into the file as ASCII. You can't possibly want that. In any case you don't need most of this.

```
int write_line(char string[MAX_LENGTH]){

    FILE *fp = fopen("client.txt", "a");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        return -1 ; 
    }
    fwrite(string, sizeof char, strlen(string), fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

But it's very suspicious for example that you aren't passing a length into this function. I'd like to see the code that reads from the socket.

Comment: `fwrite(string, sizeof char, strlen(string), fp);` can be `fprintf(fp, "%s", string);`

Comment: The socket works fine when reading to stdout using printf("%s", buffer);. For example if I have a file with  Line 1 line 2 Line 3 . It prints out line Line 1 Line 2 Line 2 to the screen but behaves differently when I pass the buffer to the function.

Comment: @immibis Certainly, but it's less efficient, due to interpreting the format string.

Comment: @ejb @immibis  Here is the error I am getting now `fwrite(string, sizeof char, strlen(string), fp);`
                           ^
`client.c:440:27: error: too few arguments to function 'fwrite'`

Comment: @atkawa7 So what happened when you fixed it as per above?

Comment: @ejb  I getting few args error. But when when I look at manpages there should be 4 args which is the same as your code

Comment: I repeat. What happened when you fixed it *as above*? I'm not interested in your typing errors. You could always try cut and paste.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90839/discussion-between-atkawa7-and-ejp).

Comment: I'm not aware of any errors in the code above, but I haven't compiled it.I've only been writing C code since 1982. I do expect any competent programmer to be able to fix any errors that may be present.

Comment: Always `sizeof char` == 1